# Thymeleaf multiple result in condition

Tags: javascript, java, html, thymeleaf

I want to check some condition basing on statement 'myStatus' and if it is `true` - change background color to red and disable element (user could not click it), if it is `false` - change color to green. I know how to change color (and it works fine):

```
th:style="${myObject.myStatus} == true ? 'background-color:red' : 'background-color:green'"
```

but how is it possile to `disable` element in this line? I tried something like:

```
th:style="${myObject.myStatus} == true ? 'background-color:red'  'disabled:false' : 'background-color:green'"

th:style="${myObject.myStatus} == true ? 'background-color:red'  'disabled' : 'background-color:green'"

th:style="${myObject.myStatus} == true ? 'background-color:red' & disable : 'background-color:green'"
```

but it doesnt work... how is it possible to solve this problem?

@UPDATE

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getObject/{someID}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAttr(@PathVariable(value="someID") String id, Model myObject){
    myObject.addAttribute("myObject", this.objectCreator.getObjects());
    return "/chosenobject";
}
```

and it works (because colors works fine). I use it in `form` element.

Answer (score 0):

To disable a HTML element you have to use the HTML attribute `disabled`: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_disabled.asp. You can do this with Thymeleaf as the following:

```
th:disabled="${myObject.myStatus}"
```

is assume `myObject.myStatus` is either a true of false boolean value

To set the color conditionally do the following:

```
th:style="${myObject.myStatus} ? 'background-color:red' : 'background-color:green'"
```

Comment: unfortunately it does not work. nothing happens with green and red elements, both are still clickable. Do you have any else idea?

Comment: what HTML elements are you using? a <button> oder a <div> oder a <a>? Can you provide me your Java MvC Controller where you pass the myObject entity to your view

Comment: does `this.objectCreator.getObjects()` return an Array/List of objects? You aren't able to use `disabled` attribute on a <form> element. Try using it on all of your <input> and <button> elements in your form which want to disable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript to disable an element if a condition sent from the controller evaluates to true (or false).

```
document.getElementById("id").disabled = true;
```

You can also mock the `disabled` attribute in CSS with `pointer-events:none` like this:

```
th:style="${myObject.myStatus} == true ? 'background-color:red;' : 'background-color:green; pointer-events: none;'"
```